# How to use the setEnv variable in apache?

Tags: apache, setenv

I need to set my apache environment to 'foobar'

I know I need to set in in my vhost, but what should I type there and where?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) sets a particular variable to some value, so you need something like

```
SetEnv varname varvalue
```

If this is for a specific virtual host, and you have access to the Apache configuration files, this would go inside the `<VirtualHost>` directive for that virtual host.

If you don't have control of the config files, you'll need to put it in a `.htaccess` file. But for this to work, `SetEnv` must be allowed in `.htaccess` files, which is specified using the [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive.

Comment: I have never done or used Apache and now as I am setting up Git with Smart HTTP protocol I have this little problem. In the manual they are talking about a command such as `SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /opt/git`. In the linux I don't have an access to a command called `SetEnv` but `setenv`. I quite frankly don't know where should I be putting this command in. Would you be able to give me a hint?

Comment: `SetEnv` isn't a command you type in a terminal. It's a directive you put into the Apache configuration files. You should probably create a new question that describes your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I definitely will. I figured that one the hard way. :) As I said I know nothing about Apache and in general very little about Linux. Cheers

Comment: @Mehrad, I would like to know if you have found the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I configured a python/django WSGI environment.
Loading modules and `SetEnv`'ing all day long.
Did not work. The vars would just not show up.

What did work was this: https://gist.github.com/GrahamDumpleton/b380652b768e81a7f60c

Graham describes how to basically clone your wsgi.py file and then use a different one for each environment (production, test, dev) and setting your environment vars in there with `os.environ['whatever'] = 'you like!'`