# How to fix `Undefined index: db_host ` in phalcon config

Tags: phalcon

I have configured server. At last I am getting this issue to make connection.

This is New Linux server as per http://157.245.105.194/test.php

Let me know what is wrong in the code given at : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M0iqC4_5kGQVgR6aKhKFAwxbpwTOyYN7PyEgjBfL3mQ/edit?usp=sharing

At http://157.245.105.194/styleogram/fs/site/wwwroot/public/

we are getting:

```
===========
Notice: Undefined index: db_host in /var/www/html/styleogram/fs/site/wwwroot/app/config/config.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined index: db_user in /var/www/html/styleogram/fs/site/wwwroot/app/config/config.php on line 57

Notice: Undefined index: db_password in /var/www/html/styleogram/fs/site/wwwroot/app/config/config.php on line 58

Notice: Undefined index: db_name in /var/www/html/styleogram/fs/site/wwwroot/app/config/config.php on line 59

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /var/www/html/styleogram/fs/site/wwwroot/app/config/config.php:60 
Stack trace: 
#0 [internal function]: PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', NULL, NULL, Array) 
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->connect(Array) 
#2 /var/www/html/styleogram/fs/site/wwwroot/app/config/config.php(60): Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->__construct(Array) 
#3 [internal function]: {closure}() 
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\Di\Service->resolve(NULL, Object(Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault)) 
#5 [internal function]: Phalcon\Di->get('db', NULL) 
#6 [internal function]: Phalcon\Di->getShared('db') 
#7 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->_getConnection(Object(Article), NULL) 
#8 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->getReadConnection(Object(Article)) 
#9 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model->getReadConnection() 
#10 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->_executeSelect(Array, Array, NU in /var/www/html/styleogram/fs/site/wwwroot/app/config/config.php on line 60
===========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see is because your `$_SERVER` superglobal does not contain the elements you are looking for in your code. You can easily see this in the `phpinfo()` page you posted (check Apache Information section).

```
$connection = new MysqlAdapter(
    [
        "host"     => $_SERVER['db_host'],
        "username" => $_SERVER['db_user'],
        "password" => $_SERVER['db_password'],
        "dbname"   => $_SERVER['db_name']
    ]
];
```

You can remove the references to the `$_SERVER` array and use strings with the actual information for your installation. For instance `$_SERVER['db_host']` could be `localhost` for you.

Once you do those replacements, check if the error persists - if not, then you have connected to your database correctly.

You can also use the [Phalcon\Config](https://docs.phalcon.io/latest/en/config) object to store configuration data, such as database connection parameters as defined above, instead of setting them in the `$_SERVER` array.

Alternatively if you want this information to be in the `$_SERVER` array, then you will have to use the `SetEnv` in the virtualhost of your apache information.

[How to use the setEnv variable in apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638637/how-to-use-the-setenv-variable-in-apache)

Comment: Perfect Solution!